# How do i configure X-Frames-Option in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonata-admin

I want to show SonarQube widgets in different website. I'm trying to use iframe but it is giving console error -

Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not configurable. If you want to override it and allow some other domains to show, you have to override this header on your http frontend.